# Few problems creating an Android game

Tags: android

Im having a few issues with a game that Im making
First of, im making a Tower Defence game and, has you probably know, in a Tower Defence game, the "Monsters" in the game changing their routes every time you block them with a Turret.

Now, the main idea is that when you build a turret the monsters will recalculate their route. The route is calculated like this: before the monster is created it gets a Trail object that gets a direction, a starting point and an ending.
The Trail has an X and Y that increases every call and checks if a turret is located in that coordinates. If a turret is located, the Trail creates 2 new Trail objects, gets the correct one and adds it to himself, that creates a recursive object.
Now I dont know how to write all of this in Java, and if I go with this method, that it will take alot of resources (I think).

The second problem that I have is about drawing a layout over a SurfaceView.
I made a pause button, and when im clicking it the main Thread (the one that draws the game) is supposed to be stopped. Now when the thread is stopped the pause screen should be visible, but the problem is, that if the thread stops, any touch on the screen wouldn't be detected. So I tried to create a RelativeLayout, add to it the Surface and inflate the pause.xml file that containes a FrameLayout with 2 buttons: Resume and Quit, and when the pause button is clicked the FrameLayout should be visible but thats not working.
(I tried again with RelativeLayour instead, but that didn't work either)

Thanks, and if you didn't understanded something please tell me and I will try to be more understandable.

**EDIT - THE CODE**

pause.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pauseContent"
    android:background="#AA000000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible">
        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resume"
            android:layout_width="100px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Resume" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/quit"
            android:layout_width="100px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/resume"
            android:text="Quit" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

GameActivity.java

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    private RelativeLayout mainLayout;
    private GameView gameView;
    private RelativeLayout pauseContent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mainLayout=new RelativeLayout(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.pause, null);
        pauseContent=(RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.pauseContent);

        gameView=new GameView(GameActivity.this, getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());

        mainLayout.addView(gameView);
        mainLayout.addView(pauseContent, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        setContentView(mainLayout);
    }
}
```

(I deleted some of the code that wasn't needed to be shown)
In my game I created a Button object that works like the android UI Button (with the click listener...), now, I created the pause button that when he will be clicked, the pause layout should be visible - that doesn't works.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You need to post some of your code for the second question, for us to check where it fails. And the first question is too vague, tell us what you tried.

Comment: For your first part look for a decent path finding algorithm such as A* or dijkstra's, I wouldnt advise you invent your own.

Comment: @Steven I checked those algorithms and they look fine, but I dont know how to import them to my game, in Java. If you have some tutorials to give me I will be happy to read them. Thanks!

Comment: Just google Java implementations of these.